# How to properly customize React-Bootstrap Saas variables in Next.js?

Tags: css, sass, next.js, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a new Next.js project, and I'm having a hard time customizing bootstrap sass variables on my project, just like this: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#customize-bootstrap. But this throwed following error:

> Selector ":root" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

I found out on [this article](https://papidev.hashnode.dev/nextjs-selector-is-not-pure-ckhbv5jvo00lzhys10b9ybsg7) that for some reason, Next.js allows global css only in the root App component. So I have imported bootstrap on my global.scss file which I'm import in _app.tsx.

My directory looks like this:

```
pages
  ⌞ _app.tsx
  ⌞ index.tsx
styles
  ⌞ global.scss
```

In _app.tsx,

```
import '../styles/globa.scss'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

And in global.scss,

```
@import './variables'

$primary: red;

@import '/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

But this wouldn't change my primary button color. I also tried working on other variables, but none of them really works. I would appreciate any ideas or any ways to debug whether variables are properly set. Thanks!

Dependencies:

- next 11.1.0
- react 17.0.2
- react-bootstrap 1.6.1
- boostrap 5.1.0

Comment: Try removing the `bootstrap.min.css` import from `_app`.

Comment: @juliomalves It removes all boostrap styling from my app.

Comment: I fixed this by adjusting the import: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#customize-bootstrap
`@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you misspell *import '../styles/global.scss'* in _app/tsx

Comment: This should be a `comment` not `answer`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32709444)